# Meaningful plotting for the graph with many countries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My csv file is as below. The complete file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lzz2jlbehjc2y2l6nudd8/sales.csv?rlkey=i3xrq3x8zd20y4vj3u8024t43&dl=0)

sample rows

```
Country,create_date,SalesIndex
Austrailia,2023-07-16,0.66
Macedonia,2023-07-17,0.48
UK,2023-07-18,0.2
Newzealand,2023-07-19,0.50000000000000011
India,2023-07-15,7.89
Macedonia,2023-07-19,1.5800000000000003
Indonesia,2023-07-19,45.709999999999987
India,2023-07-19,7.91
Portugal,2023-07-22,226.17999999999986
```

My code to generate the graph is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')

# Convert the 'create_date' column to datetime type
df['create_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'])

# Create a plot for each unique user_email
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for Country, data in df.groupby('Country'):
    data.plot(x='create_date', y='SalesIndex', ax=ax, label=Country)
# Set the title and labels for the plot
plt.title('Total Data Billed per Country')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Total Data Billed (GB)')

# Display the legend
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The graph is generated as below. However Is there any better way to generate the grpah as the below I am not able to find which is for which country? Also for the coutries with almots similar data the line almost overlaps?

[image: graph]

Comment: Wecome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, we can just make it more understandable by adding markers or different colors.

I did a small try by adding markers and a grid. It may help you. Also attached screenshot of my output.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
df['create_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 7))
color_palette = plt.cm.get_cmap('tab20', len(df['Country'].unique()))

for i, (country, data) in enumerate(df.groupby('Country')):
    ax.plot(data['create_date'], data['SalesIndex'], label=country, color=color_palette(i))
    ax.scatter(data['create_date'], data['SalesIndex'], color=color_palette(i), s=40)

plt.title('Total Billed per Country')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Total Data Billed (GB)')

plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]